# Initializing an object as class member resulting in linking error?

Tags: variables, compilation-errors, linker

I'm a little dumbfounded as to why this isn't working. I keep getting the following linker error:

```cpp
In file included from src\ac.cpp:1:0:
src/ac.h:9:21: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #define RECEIVE_PIN 0
                     ^
src/ac.h:14:26: note: in expansion of macro 'RECEIVE_PIN'
     static IRrecv irrecv(RECEIVE_PIN);
                          ^
src/ac.h:9:21: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
 #define RECEIVE_PIN 0
                     ^
src/ac.h:14:26: note: in expansion of macro 'RECEIVE_PIN'
     static IRrecv irrecv(RECEIVE_PIN);
                          ^
*** [.pio\build\esp32cam\src\ac.cpp.o] Error 1
*** [.pio\build\esp32cam\src\main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

I am simply trying to initialize the IR receiver with `static IRrecv irrecv(RECEIVE_PIN);`, but the compiler is refusing to link it together.

```cpp
#ifndef _AC_H_
#define _AC_H_

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRrecv.h>
#include <IRutils.h>

#define RECEIVE_PIN 0

class IR
{
public:
    static IRrecv irrecv(RECEIVE_PIN);
    static decode_results results;
    void initRecv();
    bool waitForIR();
};

extern IR ir;

#endif
```

If I do `static IRrecv irrecv;` it successfully compiles, but I'm unsure if I can pass the pin variable after the fact.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/initialize-static-variables-in-c-class

Comment: what happens if you use RCV_PIN? ... looks like RECEIVE_PIN is a macro

Comment: @Mat It doesn't seem to be possible to change the value after initializing it

Comment: @jsotola I've rewritten it in various formats. I've tried all kinds of data types, names, and initializing it as `irrecv(0)` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static data members have to be defined *outside* the class declaration.
The initialization happens at the point where the members are defined:

**file ac.h:**

```cpp
//...

class IR
{
public:
    // Static data members are declared only:
    static IRrecv irrecv;
    static decode_results results;
    void initRecv();
    bool waitForIR();
};
```

**file ac.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "ac.h"

#define RECEIVE_PIN 0

// Definitions and initializations of static data members:
IRrecv IR::irrecv(RECEIVE_PIN);
decode_results IR::results;
```